# Adaptive input width css

Tags: html, css, width

I'm having a problem with the text input, can it be made 'adaptive'? If I add the input are width, there will be too much unnecessary space in the left side. Again, if it's not wide enough, you can't see the whole input.

[image: width set to 50px]

[image: too much space in left, if the input is short]

```
        input[type="text"]{
        max-width: 50px;
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: whitesmoke;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```
<input type="text" id="answer5" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Is there a way to make the area 'adaptive'? So if the answer is just 1, the text in the right is closer to the number, and if the answer is longer, you could see the whole answer.

thanks

Comment: hey please provide more clear information of what you want!

Comment: @MDHesari added a small explanation; Is there a way to make the area 'adaptive'? So if the answer is just 1, the text in the right is closer to the number, and if the answer is longer, you could see the whole answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a span? Why the input field as it is disabled?

Comment: @RobinV. That just prints the calculation of inputs that you have given beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using a flex container and `flex-grow: 1` for the child element which should take up the most available space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container [type="text"] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 .5em;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: .5em.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label for="textInput" class="first">The following number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="textInput">
  <span class="result">is numeric</span>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpd5hzL4/)

Answer (score 0):

do not use max-width and instead use width with percent or px. that will make the element adaptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default width to correspond with that of 1 character (depends on font-settings).
Then update on every keypress:

```
$(".answer").keypress(function() {
  this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 12) + 'px';
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h843spto/)

If you don't enter data into the field manually but set it through code, you can use `change`. This will work for both situations but will only visible when focus is not on the input-field anymore:

```
$(".answer").change(function() {
    this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 12) + 'px';
})
```